# jquery if statement animate back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

How do I add an if statement when the right image is at +400px, then animate back to -400px... when hovering the right image?

```
$('#left img').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#right img').animate({
    left: '+=400px'
  }, 700);                            

});
$('#right img').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#left img').animate({
    left: '-=400px'
  }, 700);

});
```

Something similar to [this](http://www.hyundaiusa.com).
(the two main images on the site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why simply not use: [**mouseleave**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

```
$("#left img").mouseenter(function(){
     //+400
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      //-400
    });
```

Peraphs is the same of mouseover / mouseout AND hover